# no active/idle session still temporary files present in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have used below query to find out temporary files present in postgresql-9.6 instance

```
SELECT datname, temp_files AS "Temporary files",temp_bytes AS "Size of temporary files" FROM pg_stat_database 
order by temp_bytes desc;
```

result is as per below

[image]

why Postgresql maintaining temporary tables when there is no active session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what those numbers are. They are totals over the lifetime of the database. They are not numbers for currently present temporary files.